# Existe alguma maneira de se lançar exceção quando o fwrite não consegue escrever?

Tags: php

Costumo utilizar a classe `SplFileObject` para poder trabalhar com arquivos. O mesmo não ocorre com os sockets, quando necessário conectar, sendo necessário utilizar a função `fsockopen` ou `stream_socket_client`.

Preciso que, em um determinado trecho de código, caso o `fwrite` não consiga escrever os dados, lance uma exceção.

Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso?

Comment: Qual erro da? um fatal error?

Comment: @rray, especificamente não consiga escrever os dados. Ou seja, algum tipo de erro de conexão, ou demora. Não sei como dizer exatamente, mas penso em um erro ao escrever dados para uma conexão socket

Comment: Já tentou usar o `set_error_handler`, quando acontecer um erro vc captura ele e lança um exception.

Comment: Eu queria capturar o erro específico de um `fwrite`

Comment: Seria isso http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php#81269 ?

Comment: `fwrite() === FALSE`? Será que dá pra fazer um `fwrite($data, 'teste') or $this->callException()`? Tenho certeza que não vai aceitar um throw depois do `OR`

Comment: Erro específico tipo, com detalhes do ocorrido ?

Comment: Não precisa ser específico. O `fwrite` só precisa não conseguir escrever na conexão atual.

Comment: Ainda tem dúvida sobre o assunto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Poderia realizar algo assim:**

```
> $resultado = fwrite('log.txt'); 
> if (false === $resultado) 
> {
>   throw new RuntimeException('Erro Especifico'); 
> }
```

Comment: Certinho. Vale lembrar que, para algumas funções, é uma boa ideia colocar `@` antes, para não emitir warnings chatos no meio do seu código :D